# How to convert timestamps to dates in Bash?

Tags: bash, date, unix-timestamp

I need a shell command or script that converts a Unix timestamp to a date. The input can come either from the first parameter or from stdin, allowing for the following usage patterns:

```
ts2date 1267619929
```

and

```
echo 1267619929 | ts2date
```

Both commands should output "Wed Mar  3 13:38:49 2010".

Answer (score 750, accepted):

On systems with [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Seconds-since-the-Epoch.html) >= 5.3.0, e.g. Linux you can use:

```
date -d @1267619929
```

Comment: One-liner: `date -d @$(date -u +%s)`

Comment: What is the `@` for? I don't see that in the GNU man page at all.

Comment: @mehaase - the man page notes that the date string is too complex to be documented in the manpage, so it is described in info: **info '(coreutils) date invocation'**

Comment: `brew install coreutils; gdate -d @1267619929`

Comment: `info 'Date input formats'`  gets you straight to `date`'s formatting info node, with the pertinent Robert Grudin quote, and then a menu of format specifiers.

Comment: In a pipe: `echo 1267619929 | date -d @$(</dev/stdin)`

Comment: This didn't work with my timestamp. My timestamp is: "1673568280102". The output of this command was: "Sun Jan  2 12:00:00 AM PST 167356828" but if I use https://www.epochconverter.com/ it shows the correct timestamp: Thursday, January 12, 2023 4:04:40.102 PM It looks like your command doesn't account for time zones?

Comment: @RaleighL. usually UNIX/epoch time is measured in seconds, whereas your example is in milliseconds. So if you remove the final 3 digits, you should find it gives the date & time that you're expecting.

Comment: If your converted date looks like 50000 years from the future you should try removing the last 3 digits from the input. My best guess is that these were milliseconds. https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ ignored them and the results made sense. :-)

Answer (score 237):

```
date -r <number>
```

works for me on Mac OS X.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't handle fractions of a second.

Comment: And it's confusing because it's not working in that way on most linux systems, because:
    
    freddy@hades ~ % date --help | grep -- -r
    -r, --reference=FILE      display the last modification time of FILE

Comment: while the comments on this answer are true, these are not rafa's fault, and they don't diminish his answer.

Answer (score 34):

This version is similar to **chiborg's** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2371261), but it eliminates the need for the external `tty` and `cat`. It uses `date`, but could just as easily use `gawk`. You can change the shebang and replace the double square brackets with single ones and this will also run in `sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG=C
if [[ -z "$1" ]]
then
    if [[ -p /dev/stdin ]]    # input from a pipe
    then
        read -r p
    else
        echo "No timestamp given." >&2
        exit
    fi
else
    p=$1
fi
date -d "@$p" +%c
```

Comment: +1: very complete answer and I think date is faster than gawk.

Comment: @Bruno, how do you know date is faster than gawk.?

Comment: @Bruno, @ghostdog74: On my system, `gawk` is (very roughly) 15% faster than `date` in a timed `for` loop consisting only of `gawk 'BEGIN { print strftime("%c", 1256571985); }'` or `date -d '@1256571985' +%c` with output redirected to `/dev/null`.

Comment: I chose this as the "best" answer because the script satisfies the "date input via parameter or stdin" better. Thanks for enhancing my shellscripting skills!

Comment: date is marginally (5%) faster than gawk for me (mac osx 10.9.2, date 8.23, gawk 4.1.1), but the real advantage of (g)awk is to accept a pipe of a column of many timestamps (see my answer below), which makes the script e.g. 250x as fast for 1000 timestamps.

Comment: Note that my answer meets the OP's requirements as stated in the question, but the now accepted answer doesn't.

Answer (score 22):

You can use GNU date, for example,

```
$ sec=1267619929
$ date -d "UTC 1970-01-01 $sec secs"
```

or

```
$ date -ud @1267619929
```

Comment: On macOS, you can run `brew install coreutils` and then use the `gdate` command, e.g. `gdate --date @1660859222` which yields `Thu Aug 18 14:47:02 PDT 2022`.

Answer (score 20):

You can get formatted date from timestamp like this

```
date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "@timestamp"
```

Comment: Other way around:   date -ud "@1585667718" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: Instead, use `-Is` for ISO format, seconds precision

Answer (score 15):

I use this cross-platform one-liner:

```
date -d @1267619929 2>/dev/null || date -r 1267619929
```

It should work both in macOS and modern versions of popular Linux distributions.

Answer (score 11):

Since Bash 4.2 you can use `printf`'s `%(datefmt)T` format:

```
$ printf '%(%c)T\n' 1267619929
Wed 03 Mar 2010 01:38:49 PM CET
```

That's nice, because it's a shell builtin. The format for *datefmt* is a string accepted by `strftime(3)` (see `man 3 strftime`). Here `%c` is:

> `%c`     The  preferred  date  and  time  representation  for the current
>              locale.

---

Now if you want a script that accepts an argument and, if none is provided, reads stdin, you can proceed as:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (($#)); then
    printf '%(%c)T\n' "$@"
else
    while read -r line; do
        printf '%(%c)T\n' "$line"
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this simple awk script:

```
#!/bin/gawk -f   
{ print strftime("%c", $0); }
```

Sample usage:

```
$ echo '1098181096' | ./a.awk 
Tue 19 Oct 2004 03:18:16 AM PDT
$
```

Comment: This doesn't fit the first usage - sometimes I don't want to echo the TS and use a parameter instead.

Comment: On some old busybox version, `date -s @` doesn't work, and `awk` still does! An example without a stdin would be helpful too.

Answer (score 6):

I use this when converting log files or monitoring them:

```
tail -f <log file> | gawk \
'{ printf strftime("%c", $1); for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf $i " "; print $NF }'
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, can be shortened to `awk  '{ printf strftime("%c: ", $1); $1 = ""; print $0; }'`

Answer (score 6):

In OSX, or BSD, there's an equivalent `-r` flag which apparently takes a unix timestamp.  Here's an example that runs date four times: once for the first date, to show what it is; one for the conversion to unix timestamp with `%s`, and finally, one which, with `-r`, converts what `%s` provides back to a string.

```
$  date; date +%s; date -r `date +%s`
Tue Oct 24 16:27:42 CDT 2017
1508880462
Tue Oct 24 16:27:42 CDT 2017
```

At least, seems to work on my machine.

```
$ uname -a
Darwin XXX-XXXXXXXX 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: If you already have a timestamp value and you just need to find the equivalent date, in OS X you can just type this at the command line: date -r 1509453417

Comment: That's true.  If you look at my answer, I'm actually demonstrating that.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a script that does this myself:

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG=C
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    if [  "$(tty)" = "not a tty" ]; then
            p=`cat`;
    else
            echo "No timestamp given."
            exit
    fi
else
    p=$1
fi
echo $p | gawk '{ print strftime("%c", $0); }'
```

Answer (score 4):

In this answer I copy Dennis Williamson's answer and modify it slightly to allow a vast speed increase when piping a column of many timestamps to the script. For example, piping 1000 timestamps to the original script with xargs -n1 on my machine took 6.929s as opposed to 0.027s with this modified version:

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG=C
if [[ -z "$1" ]]
then
    if [[ -p /dev/stdin ]]    # input from a pipe
    then
        cat - | gawk '{ print strftime("%c", $1); }'
    else
        echo "No timestamp given." >&2
        exit
    fi
else
    date -d @$1 +%c
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

some example:

```
$ date
Tue Mar 22 16:47:06 CST 2016

$ date -d "Tue Mar 22 16:47:06 CST 2016" "+%s"
1458636426

$ date +%s
1458636453

$ date -d @1458636426
Tue Mar 22 16:47:06 CST 2016

$ date --date='@1458636426'
Tue Mar 22 16:47:06 CST 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the previous solutions for special cases: `printf '%(%c)T\n' $timestamp` (if you have Bash>=4.2), `date -d @$timestamp` (if you have GNU Coreutils >= 5.3.0), `date -r $timestamp` (if you are on BSD/MacOS), but I needed something more portable and I opted for `jq` that I have everywhere to help with JSON:

```
jq 'todate' <<< $timestamp
```

Which could be used in a function to obtain the desired effect:

```
ts2date() { [[ -n "$1" ]] && { jq 'todate' <<< $1 ; true;} || jq 'todate' ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

While not pure bash, the following script will convert timestamps of length 13 in a string to their equivalent date in your local timezone using perl

## timestamp_to_date.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IT=$(cat /dev/stdin)
re='(.*)([0-9]{13})(.*)'
while [[ $IT =~ $re ]]; do
  TIMESTAMP=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  AS_DATE=$(echo "$TIMESTAMP" | perl -pe 's/([\d]{10})([\d]{3})/localtime $1/eg;')
  IT="${IT/$TIMESTAMP/$AS_DATE}"    
done
echo "$IT"
```

#### input

```
{"timestamp":"1573121629939","level":"DEBUG","thread":"http-nio-15372-exec-3","logger":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor"}
```

#### output

```
$ cat input | timestamp_to_date.sh

{"timestamp":"Thu Nov  7 06:13:49 2019","level":"DEBUG","thread":"http-nio-15372-exec-3","logger":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert timestamps inline in my bash history to make sense to me.

Maybe the following coming from an answer to [How do I replace a substring by the output of a shell command with sed, awk or such?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823959/how-do-i-replace-a-substring-by-the-output-of-a-shell-command-with-sed-awk-or-s/27823994) could be interesting to other readers too.
Kudos for the original sed inline code go to @Gabriel.

```
cat ~/.bash_history | sed "s/^#\([0-9]\+\)$/echo -n '#'; date -u --d @\1 '\+\%Y-\%m-\%d \%T'/e" | less
```

Comment: you should check out https://jb55.com/datefmt, I've written a C util that does just that, and it should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to format many timestamps all at once, I've written a C util called [datefmt](https://jb55.com/datefmt) that formats timestamps in a text stream:

Let’s say we have some logs that contain unix timestamps:

```
$ cat logs.txt

EVENTS  1638499687   blahblah log1
EVENTS  1638499717   blahblah log2
```

We can pipe this log into datefmt to convert these timestamps into human-readable dates:

```
$ <logs.txt datefmt

EVENTS  2021-12-02 18:48   blahblah log1
EVENTS  2021-12-02 18:48   blahblah log2
```

Of course you can customize the format as well:

```
$ <logs.txt datefmt "DATE:'%m-%d %R'"

EVENTS  DATE:'12-02 18:48'   blahblah log1
EVENTS  DATE:'12-02 18:48'   blahblah log2
```

I've packaged this in NixOS, hopefully it will trickle out to other distros soon, but for now you will need to download the tarball and build it with `make`

Answer (score -15):

In PHP

```
$unix_time = 1256571985;

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$unix_time)
```

Comment: Nice, but I just wanted to use bash.