# Convert Unix timestamp to a date string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

Is there a quick, one-liner way to convert a Unix timestamp to a date from the Unix command line?

`date` might work, except it's rather awkward to specify each element (month, day, year, hour, etc.), and I can't figure out how to get it to work properly. It seems like there might be an easier way — am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert timestamps to dates in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371248/how-to-convert-timestamps-to-dates-in-bash)

Answer (score 245, accepted):

With `date` from [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Seconds-since-the-Epoch.html) you can do:

```
date -d "@$TIMESTAMP"
```

```
# date -d @0
Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
```

(From: [BASH: Convert Unix Timestamp to a Date](http://www.antonolsen.com/2006/04/06/bash-convert-unix-timestamp-to-a-date/))

On OS X, use `date -r`.

```
date -r "$TIMESTAMP"
```

Alternatively, use `strftime()`. It's not available directly from the shell, but you can access it via [gawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations). The `%c` specifier displays the timestamp in a locale-dependent manner.

```
echo "$TIMESTAMP" | gawk '{print strftime("%c", $0)}'
```

```
# echo 0 | gawk '{print strftime("%c", $0)}'
Wed 31 Dec 1969 07:00:00 PM EST
```

Comment: Make sure to eliminate the milliseconds from the timestamp (that is only 10 digits instead of 13), otherwise you'll get invalid results (this is true for macOS' date).

Comment: I thought this was not working, until I realised I had a timestamp in millis. Chop off the last 3 digits, and you get the accurate time

Comment: The "Convert Unix Timestamp" link is broken. Archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20200930143943/https://www.antonolsen.com/2006/04/06/bash-convert-unix-timestamp-to-a-date/ . I would edit the post with the new URL, but the edit queue is full right now.

Answer (score 81):

`date -d @1278999698 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
Where the number behind `@` is the number in seconds

Comment: On OSX 10.8, it's `date -r 1278999698 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` (GMT) or simply `date -r 1278999698`

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 30):

This solution works with versions of date which do not support `date -d @`. It does not require [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) or other commands. A Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970, UTC so it is important to specify UTC in the input.

```
date -d '1970-01-01 1357004952 sec UTC'
Mon Dec 31 17:49:12 PST 2012
```

If you are on a Mac, then use:

```
date -r 1357004952
```

Command for getting epoch:

```
date +%s
1357004952
```

Credit goes to Anton: *[BASH: Convert Unix Timestamp to a Date](https://web.archive.org/web/20200930143943/https://www.antonolsen.com/2006/04/06/bash-convert-unix-timestamp-to-a-date/)*

Comment: The URL is out-of-date - use this archived version instead: https://web.archive.org/web/20200930143943/https://www.antonolsen.com/2006/04/06/bash-convert-unix-timestamp-to-a-date/

Comment: Specifying `UTC` flag is a lot simpler than that :::: `gnu-date -u -d'@1357004952'` ; `bsd-date -u -r 1357004952` ::
`Tue Jan  1 01:49:12 UTC 2013
Tue Jan  1 01:49:12 UTC 2013`

Comment: You may have misread the answer. My answer is for cases when you do not have support for `date -d @` and when you want to display the output in your local time zone.

Answer (score 11):

As @TomMcKenzie says in a comment to another answer, `date -r 123456789` is arguably a more common (i.e. more widely implemented) simple solution for times given as seconds since the Unix Epoch, but unfortunately there's no universal guaranteed portable solution.

The `-d` option on many types of systems means something entirely different than GNU Date's `--date` extension.  Sadly GNU Date doesn't interpret `-r` the same as these other implementations.  So unfortunately you have to know which version of `date` you're using, and many older Unix `date` commands don't support either option.

Even worse, POSIX `date` recognizes neither `-d` nor `-r` and provides no standard way in any command at all (that I know of) to format a Unix time from the command line (since POSIX Awk also lacks `strftime()`).  (You can't use `touch -t` and `ls` because the former does not accept a time given as seconds since the Unix Epoch.)

Note though The One True Awk available direct from Brian Kernighan does now have the `strftime()` function built-in as well as a `systime()` function to return the current time in seconds since the Unix Epoch), so perhaps the Awk solution is the most portable.

Answer (score 5):

Slight correction to dabest1's answer above. Specify the timezone as UTC, not GMT:

```
$ date -d '1970-01-01 1416275583 sec GMT'
Tue Nov 18 00:53:03 GMT 2014
$ date -d '1970-01-01 1416275583 sec UTC'
Tue Nov 18 01:53:03 GMT 2014
```

The second one is correct. I think the reason is that in the UK, daylight saving was in force continually from 1968 to 1971.

Comment: Well done for spotting *that* unexpected corner case!

Comment: Using Git Bash on Windows 10, both the GMT and UTC versions of the above command output the same thing - `Tue Nov 18 01:53:03 GMTST 2014`.

Comment: Is this definitely Bash you're using? Could this have been the Korn shell that this idiosyncratic output came from?

Answer (score 4):

If you find the notation awkward, maybe the `-R`-option does help. It outpouts the date in RFC 2822 format. So you won't need all those identifiers: `date -d @1278999698 -R`. Another possibility is to output the date in seconds in your locale: `date -d @1278999698 +%c`. Should be easy to remember. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The standard Perl solution is:

```
echo $TIMESTAMP | perl -nE 'say scalar gmtime $_'
```

(or localtime, if preferred)

Answer (score 2):

Other examples here are difficult to remember. At its simplest:

```
date -r 1305712800
```

Comment: Mixed results: does not work in ubuntu Linux but does in Mac OS X for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { print strftime("%c", 1271603087); }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your ~/.bashrc :

```
function unixts() { date -d "@$1"; }
```

Example usage:

```
$ unixts 1551276383

Wed Feb 27 14:06:23 GMT 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
python -c "from datetime import datetime; print(datetime.fromtimestamp($TIMESTAMP))"
```

Answer (score 0):

## 3 remarks:

### .1 about [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

As this question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and no answer here address `printf` *bashism*:

#### Syntax: `printf '%(fmt)T' $UNIXEPOCH`

Under bash, from V4.2, (Feb 2011), The printf builtin has a `%(fmt)T` specifier, which allows time values to use strftime-like formatting.

```
TZ=UTC LANG=C printf '%(%A %d %b %Y, %T %Z)T\n' 12345678
Saturday 23 May 1970, 21:21:18 UTC
```

Used without argument or with `-1` as argument, this will print current time:

```
printf '%(%b %d, %T)T\n' 
Aug 03, 08:42:28
```

As `printf` repeat *format sequenc* for as many argument present in command line:

```
$ TZ=UTC LANG=C printf '%(%A %d %b %Y, %T %Z)T\n' -1 123456789 $EPOCHSECONDS
Sunday 20 Nov 2022, 13:04:42 UTC
Thursday 29 Nov 1973, 21:33:09 UTC
Sunday 20 Nov 2022, 13:04:42 UTC
```

Without argument and without *`fmt`* string, `printf '%()T'` will print current time:

```
printf '%()T\n'
12:34:56

echo $(( $(TZ=UTC printf "%()T" | sed 's/:/* 3600 +/;s/:/* 60 +/') -
         $(printf "%(%s)T") % 86400 ))
0
```

### .2 The `$EPOCHSECONDS` and `$EPOCHREALTIME` integer variables

From V5.0, bash's environment present two integer variables: `$EPOCHSECONDS` which expands to the time in seconds since the Unix epoch and `$EPOCHREALTIME` which expands to the time in seconds since the Unix epoch with microsecond granularity..

```
myvar1=$(LANG=C date -d 'now -1 day' +%c)
LANG=C printf -v myvar2 '%(%c)T' $(( EPOCHSECONDS - 86400 ))
[[ $myvar1 == "$myvar2" ]] || echo "Something's wrong: '$myvar1' != '$myvar2'!"
```

Except in a very small time laps, where time rounded to second increment by one second between setting `$myvar1` and `$myvar2`, this code won't produce any output as `$myvar1` should contain exactly same string than `$myvar2`.

```
declare -p myvar{1,2}
declare -- myvar1="Tue Aug  2 11:11:35 2022"
declare -- myvar2="Tue Aug  2 11:11:35 2022"
```

As `printf` is a *builtin*, there is no *fork* for assigning string variable from UNIXTIME conversion.

The only difference would be resource footprint, then execution time.

Further informations and recommendations about `$EPOCHREALTIME`, see [How to print current time in microseconds using bash builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557346/1765658)

### .3 About GNU `date`

#### option `-f` for many entries

Using *GNU `date`*, if you plan to format a big bunch of *unixtimestamp*, you could use `date` command as a filter.

First you have to add a ***`At`*** (`@`) before each timestamp, then `date -f` could process each input lines in one operation:

```
sed 's/^/@/' < inputfile |
    date -f - +'%A %d %b %Y, %T %Z'
```

Sample:

```
seq 123456789 $(((EPOCHSECONDS-123456789)/4)) $EPOCHSECONDS |
    sed 's/^/@/' |
    LANG=C TZ=GMT date -f - +'%A %d %b %Y, %T %Z'
```

Should produce something like:

```
Thursday 29 Nov 1973, 21:33:09 GMT
Thursday 30 Jan 1986, 11:53:49 GMT
Thursday 02 Apr 1998, 02:14:29 GMT
Wednesday 02 Jun 2010, 16:35:09 GMT
Wednesday 03 Aug 2022, 06:55:49 GMT
```

### .4 Converting streamed logfile

This could be titled

##### **Convert streamed Unix timestamp to date strings in real time**.

Sample using `tail -f squid/access.log`, from a remote server.

`squid` logs look like:

> ```
> 1659526597.212 240128 192.168.0.184 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3383 CONNECT safebrowsing.googleapis.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.168.74 -
> 1659526614.078    753 192.168.0.91 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3800 CONNECT shavar.services.mozilla.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/44.236.110.253 -
> ```

To be able to remotely follow some *squid proxy* I could use this:

```
exec {fd}<> <(:) # This will open unnamed fifo.
```

Then

```
ssh root@proxyserver tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log |
    tee >(
        exec sed -ue 's/^\([0-9]\+\)\..*/@\1/'|
            stdbuf -i0 -o0 date -f - +%c >/dev/fd/$fd
     ) |
    sed -ue 's/^[0-9]\+\././'|
        paste -d '' /dev/fd/$fd -
```

This will output **without buffering**, something like this:

```
Wed Aug  3 13:36:37 2022.212 240128 192.168.0.184 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3383 CONNECT safebrowsing.googleapis.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.168.74 -
Wed Aug  3 13:36:54 2022.078    753 192.168.0.91 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3800 CONNECT shavar.services.mozilla.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/44.236.110.253 -
```

Could be stopped by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then re-run many time, until you close `$fd` unnamed fifo by:

```
exec {fd}<&-
```