# How do I convert a date from Unix time to string, in a script?

Tags: bash

To convert a date from string to Unix time, I can use `date --date "2012-02-13" +%s`.

How do I do the opposite, from Unix time to string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert from unixtime at command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249827/convert-from-unixtime-at-command-line)

Comment: Be careful, this is just for Bash GNU. As an example on Mac should be something like date -d "2012-02-13" +%s similar but not the same

Comment: @DiegoAndrésDíazEspinoza, good warning, but to clarify, this is GNU date, but not bash. The OSX version is derived from FreeBSD, where you could use `date -j 021300002012 '+%s'` or `date -v2012y -v2m -v13d '+%s'` to get something equivalent to the command in the question.

Comment: @ghoti the main title says "bash script" maybe I got confused with that thanks anyway i made a mistake becasu i wrote "date -d "2012-02-13" +%s" which is pretty the same, anyway my point was: just becareful, bash and gnu has not the same standard

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `date --date @datetime`:

```
[foo@bar ~]$date --date "2012-02-13" +%s
1329055200
[foo@bar ~]$date --date @1329055200
Mon Feb 13 00:00:00 EST 2012
[foo@bar ~]$date --date @1329055200 +"%Y-%m-%d"
2012-02-13
```

I'm not sure where the '@xxxx'  is documented though!

Comment: It's documented in the info pages. See http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats

Comment: Thanks! it's not on the `man` page which is pretty misleading

Comment: The man page does say "The date string format is more complex than is easily documented here but is fully described in the info documentation."

Answer (score 6):

The options to the `date` command depend on your operating system.

In FreeBSD:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ date -r 1332468005 '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
2012-03-22 22:00:05
```

In Linux:

```
ghoti@wopr$ date -d @1332468005 '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2012-03-22 22:00:05
```

In other operating systems, I don't know.

If you want a solution that doesn't rely on the `date` command, you can use perl or gawk, if they happen to be installed on the machine you're using.

```
ghoti@wopr$ gawk -v when=1332468005 'BEGIN{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T", when); }'
2012-03-22 22:00:05
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done through `awk`:

```
$  date --date "2012-02-13" +%s | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $1); }'
2012-02-13
```

or any other tool that provides an interface to `strftime()`

Comment: This works in gawk, as I mentioned in my answer, but the `strftime()` function is not included in most other awk implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--date=@` option to pass the Unix timestamp, and use the format according to the output you want.

```
$ date --date "2012-02-13" +%s
1329062400
$ date --date=@1329062400 +%F
2012-02-13
```