# unix time to date and replace in bash using awk

Tags: bash, awk, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert  unix time to date and time;

```
1436876820 blah1 stop none john
1436876820 blah0 continu none john
1436876821 blah2 stop good bob
```

I would like to convert the first column to have two more column date and time as below

```
14-07-15 13:27:00 blah1 stop none john
14-07-15 13:27:00 blah0 continu none john
14-07-15 13:27:01 blah2 stop good bob
etc..
```

So I have started to do the following.

```
IN="${1}"

for i in $(awk '{print $1}' ${IN});
do

DD=$(date -d @${i} +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

awk '{ ${1}="'"${DD}"'" }' < ${IN}


done
```

This does not work due to the syntax and give such of error:

```
awk: { ${1}="14-07-2015 13:27" }
awk:          ^ syntax error
```

I could use sed instead of awk:

```
sed "s/^1........./${DD}/" ${IN}
```

Any help with awk is really welcome.
Al.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to bash script format unix time to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832393/how-to-bash-script-format-unix-time-to-string)

Comment: this is no much at the conversion that the issue is; more at the substitution of the unix time to date.

Comment: Off-hand, you probably want to quote the string you're passing into date.  `DD=$(date -d "@${i}" +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: awk is not shell, it has it's own syntax. Just change `${1}` to `$1` to get rid of the syntax error. The whole thing should be rewritten though. Do you have GNU awk?

Comment: mm.. I have tried but does not help; this is same error

Comment: Changing the ${1} to $1 does not change anything :(

Comment: It does change something, it gets rid of the obvious syntax error. There's nothing else in your posted script that would produce a syntax error, you must have another problem in an earlier part of the shell script you aren't showing us, probably a mismatched double quote. Anyway, I just posted an awk script to do this a better way even if you don't have gawk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the shell loop and just do it one awk invocation:

```
awk '{
    cmd = "date -d @" $1 " +\"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S\""
    if ( (cmd | getline dd) > 0 ) {
        $1 = dd
    }
    close(cmd)
    print
}' "$1"
```

If you have GNU awk you can just use it's internal strftime() instead of the date+getline:

```
awk '{
    $1 = strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",$1)
    print
}' "$1"
```

Comment: superbe! nice one with awk :)