# How To Convert Date "+%F %T" to RFC 2822 Format For List Of Dates

Tags: linux, bash, date, datetime, awk

I have read the following question: [Convert from Unix time at the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249827/convert-from-unix-time-at-the-command-line) and [Convert Any Format In Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62213/convert-any-date-format-in-unix). I have tried a few different ways to convert my time `2017-10-12 00:34:26` which is in the `date "+%F %T"` format to the `date -R` format or `Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:34:26 -0400`.

Since I need to convert a list of dates like the following, I'm using `$etime` as a variable for just one line of the file (until I got it working).

`file1`:

```
2017-10-12 00:22:26
2017-10-12 00:25:26
2017-10-12 00:28:26
2017-10-12 00:31:26
2017-10-12 00:34:26
```

1st attempt:

```
etime=$(echo "2017-10-12 00:34:26"); date -Rd @$etime
```

2nd attempt:

```
etime=$(echo "2017-10-12 00:34:26"); | gawk '{print strftime("%c", $0)}'
```

Although these two didn't work, I was hoping to get them to work and then just loop the command for each line in `file1` so the result would be:

```
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:22:26 -0400
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:25:26 -0400
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:28:26 -0400
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:31:26 -0400
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:34:26 -0400
```

Does anyone know an efficient way to convert these date formats in a list? Your help and support for the question is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires GNU date for the `-f` option:

```
date -R -f file1
```

resulting in

```
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:22:26 -0400
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:25:26 -0400
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:28:26 -0400
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:31:26 -0400
Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:34:26 -0400
```

From the `date` man page:

> `-f`, `--file=DATEFILE`
>   like `--date`; once for each line of *`DATEFILE`*

and

> `-d`, `--date=STRING`
>   display time described by *`STRING`*, not 'now'

Answer (score 1):

GNU **awk** solution:

```
awk '{ gsub(/[-:]/," "); print strftime("%c %z",mktime($0)) }' file
```

- `%c` - The locale’s “appropriate” date and time representation. (This is ‘%A %B %d %T %Y’ in the "C" locale.)
- `%z` - The time zone offset in a ‘+HHMM’ format (e.g., the format necessary to produce RFC 822/RFC 1036 date headers)

Comment: So close! Do you know how to get rid of the AM/PM in the output? I just need it on the 24 hour clock.

Comment: I'm getting an output like this (first line) `Thu, Oct 12, 2017 12:22:26 AM -0400` but I thought RFC would be like this: `Thu, Oct 12, 2017 00:22:26 -0400`. Do you know how to do that? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Getting closer...now I got this `Thu Oct 12 00:22:26 2017 -0400`. (The year is out of place and the commas are gone).

Comment: any ideas on how to remove the `AM/PM`?

Comment: Nope :-/ It gave: `Thu, Oct 12, 2017 12:22:26 AM -0400`

Comment: Tried removing that and it didn't work. However, I don't think simply removing the AM/PM will work because times that are at 12:01 AM will not be converted to 00:01. I think it's just generating that automatically. It has something to do the with the %z format