# convert first column in a csv file from timestamp to year-month format

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Trying to convert first column in a csv file from unix timestamp to date(year-month format)

Tried `date -d @number'+%Y-%m'` and `awk`, but `awk` doesn't recognize @ when used together

Extract from a csv file :

```
 1556113878,60662402644292
 1554090396,59547403093308
```

Expected O/p

```
2019-04,60662402644292
2019-03,59547403093308
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3249936/1135424

Comment: awk recognizes `@` just fine. Not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have GNU awk (sometimes called `gawk`), try:

```
gawk -F,  '{print strftime("%Y-%m", $1),$2}' OFS=, file.csv
```

For example, consider this input file:

```
$ cat file.csv
1556113878,60662402644292
1554090396,59547403093308
```

Our command produces this output:

```
$ gawk -F,  '{print strftime("%Y-%m", $1),$2}' OFS=, file.csv
2019-04,60662402644292
2019-03,59547403093308
```

On many Linux systems, GNU awk is the default.  On others like Ubuntu, it is not but it can be easily installed: `sudo apt-get install gawk`.  On MacOS, GNU awk can be installed via homebrew.

Comment: This worked thanks a lot. Upvoted your post, but looks like a newbie's cast doesn't show up

Comment: @Bt_code Glad it worked for you and thanks.  (If I recall correctly, it takes 15 rep points to be able to cast upvotes.)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have GNU AWK, you may have a system Ruby, in which case you can do this:

```
▶ ruby -F, -ane \
   '$F[0] = Time.at($F[0].to_i).strftime("%Y-%m"); print $F.join(",")' FILE      
2019-04,60662402644292
2019-04,59547403093308
```

Further explanation:

- Unlike Perl's `POSIX::strftime`, system Ruby should ship with the `Time` module. Thus my choice of Ruby.
- The command line options are `-F,` is the same as AWK; `-n` is the same as sed; `-a` turns on AWK-like auto-split; `-e` is the same as sed.
- `$F` is similar to AWK's `$0` and `$F[0]` is similar to AWK's `$1`. `$F[0].to_i` converts the Epoch time string in the first field to an integer.