# Convert Windows Timestamp to date using PHP on a Linux Box

Tags: php, date, active-directory, timestamp

I have an intranet running on a linux box, which authenticates against Active Directory on a Windows box, using LDAP through PHP.

I can retrieve a user's entry from AD using LDAP and access the last login date from the php array eg:

```
echo $adAccount['lastlogontimestamp'][0]; // returns something like 129802528752492619
```

If this was a Unix timestamp I would use the following PHP code to convert to a human readable date:

```
date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $lastlogontimestamp);
```

However, this does not work.  Does anyone know how I can achieve this or indeed if it is possible to do so from a Linux box?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php), the windows timestamp you have there is the number of 100-ns since Jan 1st 1601. Therefore, you could just convert it to a unix timestamp using the following formula:

```
tUnix = tWindow/(10*1000*1000)-11644473600;
```

You divide by `10*1000*1000` to convert to seconds since Jan 1st 1601 and then you discount `11644473600` which is the number of seconds between Jan 1601 and Jan 1970 (unix time).

So in PHP:

```
date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $lastlogontimestamp/10000000-11644473600);
```

EDIT: Interestingly, I got a different offset than Baba. I got mine with Java:

```
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance(); date1.set(1601, 1, 1);
Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance(); date2.set(1970, 1, 1);
long dt = date2.getTimeInMillis() - date1.getTimeInMillis();
System.out.println(String.format("%f", dt / 1000.0)); // prints "11644473600.000000"
```

According to this SO: [Ways to Convert Unix/Linux time to Windows time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5471379/1137043) my offset is correct.

Comment: I got a different offset with PHP: strtotime("1601-01-01") - strtotime("1970-01-01") = 11644470000.  This is an hour (3600 seconds) different to yours, but as MSDN says to use your Java derived value I will use your answer.  Thank you for your assistance and thank you to Baba.

Comment: I’ve also seen 11644477200 (as Baba used). That’s at least three different values. Granted, the difference isn’t huge and may not matter in some contexts, but it’s good to know what the correct value to subtract should be regardless of time-zone. I’m going to go with the `…7360…` value as [seen in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724228).

Comment: @Synetech Yeah, the whole date thing is a bloody mess. It always depends on which system you are using.

Answer (score 7):

Since windows is not in seconds but in `nano seconds` you need to round it up by dividing it by `10000000` you also need to remove seconds between `1601-01-01 and 1970-01-01`since windows timestamp start from `1601-01-01`

```
function convertWindowsTimestamp($wintime) {
   return $wintime / 10000000 - 11644477200;
}

$lastlogontimestamp = convertWindowsTimestamp("129802528752492619");
$date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $lastlogontimestamp);
var_dump($date);
```

Output

```
string '30-04-2012 10:47:55' (length=19)
```

Comment: Can you explain what your function is doing ie, why divide by 10million and then subtract 11644477200?