# Convert timestamp from joulemeter to human readable form

Tags: php, timestamp

Currently i'm collecting data using joulemeter developed from Microsoft.
It records data and time in timestamp format, but in different format. I try to convert using normal but couldn't get accurate time and data. And i'm going to use the data in php. Below is the data I get, first column is the record of timestamp.

```
TimeStamp (ms)   Total Power (W)     CPU (W)     Monitor (W)     Disk (W)    Base (W)    Application (W)
63573171824975  27      0.2 4.4 0   22.4    --
63573171825988  27      0.2 4.4 0   22.4    --
63573171827002  26.9    0.1 4.4 0   22.4    --
63573171828016  27      0.1 4.4 0   22.4    --
63573171829030  27      0.1 4.4 0   22.4    --
63573171830044  27      0.1 4.4 0   22.4    --
63573171831058  26.9    0   4.4 0   22.4    --
63573171832074  26.9    0   4.4 0   22.4    --
63573171833086  26.9    0.1 4.4 0   22.4    --
63573171834100  26.9    0.1 4.4 0   22.4    --
63573171835115  26.9    0   4.4 0   22.4    --
```

I have do searched online but found no solution.
That is a thread found here 
[Microsoft](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9e7c560-7669-48a3-a9c0-fd1e1e919c2c/timestamp-in-joulemeter-tool?forum=joulemeter), but no one answer the question. Appreciate if can help.

Edited:
Additional information:
I notice that joulemeter shows the power model from 7/3/2015 4:41:08 PM
Will it start counting from this date instead of windows timestamp 1601/1970?
Which means the offset of the timestamp is different.

Comment: Do you know what that timestamp represents?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411954/convert-windows-timestamp-to-date-using-php-on-a-linux-box#answer-10412203

Comment: @mmm thx, i tried.
tUnix = tWindow/(10*1000*1000)-11644473600;
I try to use this. At the end this is the result
15-03-1601 20:50:43
the time might be correct but instead of the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after whole day of research, finally i'm able figure the solution.
The timestamp format mentioned is not an UNIX timestamp which start from
`00:00:00 1/1/1970` and currently using as start date on PHP `date()` function.
It's actually start from `0001-01-01 00:00:00`.

> number of second between `0001-01-01 00:00:00` and `00:00:00 1/1/1970` = 62136892800

**Solution:**

```
//timestamp in millisecond
$timestamp = 63573171824975/1000 - 62136892800;
echo date('r',$timeStamp);

//result = Tue, 7 Jul 2015 03:49:35 +0800
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about timestamps.  In short, they are the number of seconds passed since the Unix Epoch. (the dawn of time as far as computers are concerned).

```
$timeStamp = 63573171824975;
echo date('jS M Y, g:i:a',$timeStamp);
```

Outputs:  26th May 1940, 7:26:pm

The 'mask', in this case 'jS M Y, g:i:a', can be modified to suit the format that you wish to display the timestamp in.  Different 'masks' can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Once you understand this, switch to using PHP's DateTime Object instead. http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: thank you for reply. I have try this mask but the result i get is : 15th Aug 2016523, 3:49:am

Comment: What timestamp are you using?

Comment: Try: `echo date('jS M Y, g:i:a',time());` to prove your mask is correct.

Comment: Yes, i print as u mentioned. but the result is different.